# #NUM! error when formula calculating % complete for future dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a worksheet that shows employee assignments, as well as their contract start and end dates. in column D I calculate the percent that this contract is completed.

My formula is working for current and past dates, but future dates result in #NUM!. I have a feeling this is because the calculation is either impossible or less than 0.

I've tried to correct this but it's currently beating me. Any suggestions to fix this?

Formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF((DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d")+1)>99.99%,1,IFERROR((DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d")+1),0)))
```

Data:

```
    A       B           C           D
1   Name    Start Date  End Date    Contract % Complete
2   Allen   8/21/17     8/24/18     100.00%
3   Billy   12/4/17     12/8/18     72.16%
4   Charles 9/6/18      12/28/18    #NUM!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that a Date can not be negative and `DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"d")` tries to return a negative date.

If the date is in the future then it is `0%` finished.

Add an IFERROR to deal with that:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF((DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d")+1)>99.99%,1,IFERROR((DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"d")+1)/(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"d")+1),0))),0)
```

[image]

---

Because 1 day to Excel is 1 we can get rid of the `DATEDIF`. Then using MAX and MIN to get rid of the nested IF and IFERRORs, we can simplify the formula to:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",MAX(MIN((TODAY()-B2+1)/(C2-B2+1),1),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much